# 12.04 wireless not working

Tags: wireless, drivers, intel

I see that this problem has come up several times but none of the solutions have worked for me. I've tried the `rfkill` unblock all method. I've tried finding additional drivers but none come up. I have an Asus U56E and my wireless card is Intel N 6150

```
rfkill list all
0: i2400m-usb:1-1.1:1.0: WiMAX
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-wimax: WiMAX
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

david@david-U56E:~$ lspci | grep -i wireless
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150 (rev 67)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firmware for Intel wireless drivers (`iwlwifi) should be already packaged in the repos.

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
```

should do it. You may need a reboot for installation to take effect.